# Create drop-down menu using link_to that redirects to page when clicked?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

```
<h2>Where are you from?</h2>
    <form>
        <select name="URL" onchange="window.location.href= this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value">
        <option value="#">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="#">Michigan</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

I would like to link the stubbed out values to pages_connecticut_path and pages_michigan_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
<option><%= link_to 'Connecticut', pages_connecticut_path %></option>
<option> <%= link_to 'Michigan', pages_michigan_path %></option>
```